# QUERY FUNCTION google sheet Related Problem

Tags: sql, google-sheets, extract, data-analysis, data-cleaning

Suppose there’s a log of security related incidences for about 60 days along with instance_id. Now, there are cases when the incident is reported but the incident_id is not. This should be done only via SQL (Query Function) in Google sheets.

- Your goal is to find out - how many incidents have **incident_id** on a given day. How many percentage of incidents have a non-null id?
- The time is in UTC, so convert that into IST.
- What time of the day does the incident_id percentage is lower?
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D79GT.png)
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLmyY.png)

Please help me in solving this question.
Tried with this query but its not working
=QUERY(Problem_2!A2:B9372, "SELECT DATE_ADD(A, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AS timestamp_ist, COUNT(B) AS incidents_with_id, COUNTIF(B IS NOT NULL) AS incidents_with_non_null_id, (COUNTIF(B IS NOT NULL) / COUNT(B)) * 100 AS percentage_non_null_id GROUP BY DATE_ADD(A, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) ORDER BY percentage_non_null_id ASC")

tried with =QUERY(Problem_2!A2:B9372, "SELECT DATE_ADD(A, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) AS timestamp_ist, COUNT(B) AS incidents_with_id, COUNTIF(B IS NOT NULL) AS incidents_with_non_null_id, (COUNTIF(B IS NOT NULL) / COUNT(B)) * 100 AS percentage_non_null_id GROUP BY DATE_ADD(A, INTERVAL 5 HOUR) ORDER BY percentage_non_null_id ASC")